# Arithmetic signs in encrypted value cannot decrypt on live server in c#

Tags: c#, encryption, cryptography

I am working in a MVC3 Project. Encryption and decryption method are working fine in locally, but when I put on live some values are not hitting. I found that the arithmetic symbols like +,/ cause the problem. How can I resolve this?

My code is given below:

```
RijndaelManaged aese = new RijndaelManaged();  

public string Encrypt(string stringToEncrypt)
{
    try
    {
        aese.Mode = CipherMode.CBC;
        aese.Padding = PaddingMode.PKCS7;
        aese.BlockSize = 128;
        aese.KeySize = 128;
        aese.Key = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("bsGCslxDSrPTesVG");

        aese.IV = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("IkLNSuWfZaQdPQCS");

        byte[] inputByteArray = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(stringToEncrypt);

        ICryptoTransform crypto = aese.CreateEncryptor();
        byte[] cipherText = crypto.TransformFinalBlock(inputByteArray, 0, inputByteArray.Length);
        return (Convert.ToBase64String(cipherText));
    }
    catch
    {
        return "Encryption Error";
    }
}

public string Decrypt(string stringToDecrypt)
{
    byte[] inputByteArray = new byte[stringToDecrypt.Length + 1];
    try
    {
        aese.Mode = CipherMode.CBC;
        aese.Padding = PaddingMode.PKCS7;
        aese.BlockSize = 128;
        aese.KeySize = 128;
        aese.Key = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("bsGCslxDSrPTesVG");
        aese.IV = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("IkLNSuWfZaQdPQCS");
        inputByteArray = Convert.FromBase64String(stringToDecrypt);
        ICryptoTransform decrypto = aese.CreateDecryptor();
        byte[] plainText = aese.CreateDecryptor().TransformFinalBlock(inputByteArray, 0, inputByteArray.Length);

        return Encoding.UTF8.GetString(plainText);
    }
    catch
    {
        return "Dycription Error";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Given you're working with a web project, I'm going to guess that you're passing Base64-encoded cipher-text as a URL or similar. Because Base64 data contains characters that are interpreted differently when treated as a URL (e.g. a `+` in a URL is interpreted as <kbd>space</kbd>), your data will be corrupted if you include Base64-encoded data in a URL verbatim.

If you intend to pass Base64 data in this way, you must correctly URL-encode it (e.g. using `System.Web.HttpUtility.UrlEncode()`) before including it in the URL.

Comment: There is a URL-safe version of Base64, which uses - (minus) for value 62 and _ (underline) for value 63.  See RFC 4648 for details.

Comment: I would happily upvote that as as a separate answer, @rossum. It's much more efficient and has a static size.

Comment: Ok thanks . i got the point you mention. so is that encrypt and decrypt method is wrong ?

Answer (score 1):

There is a URL-safe version of Base64, which uses - (minus) for value 62 and _ (underline) for value 63. See [RFC 4648](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc4648.txt), section 5 for details.

Comment: so how to overcome this defect ... can i substitute with any other codes to replace the arithmetic signs..

Comment: You have two options.  Either use the URL-safe version of Base64, or else, as Iridium suggests, you need to URL encode the Base64 string before putting it into a URL.  That way, '+' is changed to "&2B" and '/' changes to "%2F".